# Telerik doesn't work after moving project to another env

Tags: asp.net, telerik

i moved my project from one env, and from then on i have issue running my application.

The error i receive below.
'Could not load file or assembly 'Telerik.Web.UI, Version=2016.2.504.45, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=121fae78165ba3d4' or one of its dependencies. Operation is not supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515)'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error code `0x80131515` usually tells that the assembly file has been blocked or not referenced properly (because VS thinks referenced assembly still untrusted). Here is an explanation from [Telerik's FAQ](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/installation/upgrading-instructions/upgrading-a-trial-to-a-developer-license-or-to-a-newer-version#could-not-load-file-or-assembly-telerikwebui-after-upgrade):

> **Operation is not supported HRESULT: 0x80131515**
>
> The HRESULT: 0x80131515 error usually means that the file was downloaded from the Internet and
>   Windows has blocked it. In such cases you need to simply do the
>   following:
>
> 1. In Windows Explorer, right-click the file.
> 2. Select Properties
> 3. Click the Unblock button.
> 4. Clear the read-only attribute.

Other things you should try to solve this issue:

**Using bin folder assembly deployment**

- Copy Telerik assemblies to \bin folder and use reference from that folder.
- Restart VS IDE.

**Using GAC assembly deployment**

- Add `Telerik.Web.UI.dll` assembly to GAC using this command:

  ```
  gacutil /i "[InstallDir]\BinXX\Telerik.Web.UI.dll
  ```

  Note: [InstallDir] belongs to Telerik location path and "X" means numeric value which should be adjusted based on folder hierarchy.
- Remove previously used `Telerik.Web.UI.dll` from bin folder and add reference to the newer one.
- Ensure that this line exists in web.config:

  ```
  <add assembly="Telerik.Web.UI, Version=2016.2.504.45, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=121FAE78165BA3D4" />
  ```
- Restart VS IDE.

If all possible solutions above are fruitless, create a new project with current Telerik assembly and all required assemblies then move old project files into new project.

Additional references:

[Could not load file or assembly 'Telerik.Web.UI'](https://www.telerik.com/forums/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-telerik-web-ui-version-2009-2-826-35#iuS7vYc6xkyIWx7-fuSK2g)

[Upgrade Compile Error](https://www.telerik.com/forums/upgrade-compile-error)

[Visual Studio Project Sample Loading Error: Operation is not supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/brada/2009/12/11/visual-studio-project-sample-loading-error-assembly-could-not-be-loaded-and-will-be-ignored-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-or-one-of-its-dependencies-operation-is-not-supported-exception-from/)

Answer (score 0):

Having two versions of Telerik DLLs in the solution is also a culprit. In my case I had subproject that was using a different version of .Net and hence, Telerik DLLs.